# Why is does this C code output 1 instead of 0?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Why does this output 1? If p[i][j] = i+j; should'nt it output 0 as when i==0 and j ==0 then p[0][0j] should be 0 as well. When I run this code it outputs 1.

```
int main(void){
    int i, j;
    int **p = (int **) malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));
    p[0] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    p[1] = p[0];
    
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for(j=0; j < 2; j++)
            p[i][j]=i + j;
            
    printf("%d\n", p[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It may help to draw a picture of the memory layout you end up with here:

```
   +---+
p: | * |
   +-|-+
     |
     V
   +---+       +---+---+
   | *-------> | 1 | 2 |
   +---+   ,-> +---+---+
   | *----'
   +---+
```

Since `p[0]` and `p[1]` point to the same place, you don't actually get the 2x2 array that the rest of the code seems to suggest.

If you rewrote the allocation code like this:

```
int **p = (int **) malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    p[i] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
```

then you would end up with memory like this:

```
   +---+
p: | * |
   +-|-+
     |
     V
   +---+       +---+---+
   | *-------> | 0 | 1 |
   +---+       +---+---+
   | *---.     +---+---+
   +---+  `--> | 1 | 2 |
               +---+---+
```

And now you would find that `p[0][0]` would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because `p[1]` and `p[0]` are the same pointer, and therefore `p[1][0]` is the same object as `p[0][0]`.  So when you have `i==1` and `j==0`, you store 1 to that object, which overwrites the 0 you put there when `i==0` and `j==0`.

Comment: Doesn't these [] dereference the pointer? I thought p[1] = p[0] would be the same as p[1] = 0;

Comment: Why so?  `p[0]` isn't 0, it's the pointer you got back from `malloc`.  Yes, `p[0]` dereferences the pointer `p`, but since `p` is a pointer to a pointer, the result of `p[0]` is a pointer, not a number.

Comment: Okay I was thinking of it as a int. Ints are automatically set to 0 but this is a int pointer not a int. Wait so if i just have an int pointer and I set another int pointer equal to that int pointer then what is that value? int* i, j; i = *j; what is the value of i?

Comment: @aadre44 *"Ints are automatically set to 0"* - no they're not, except for variables with static (or thread local) storage duration, neither of which you are using in this case

Comment: @UnholySheep why is that the case? If I dont initialize an int variable and print it prints a 0. I just ran it in my c program and that was the output

Comment: @aadre44 uninitialized variables have *indeterminate value* - it could print any number. Here's a simple example where exactly that happens: https://godbolt.org/z/GTha4Wf1o

Comment: @aadre44: For some int variables (eg ones with static duration - such a global variables) they will always be 0. For others (eg local variables) they *may* be 0 (and often will), but this is not guaranteed, and running the program again may give different results. Or, technically, it can crash, or do anything, since reading an uninitialised value us undefined behaviour.